# Is there any equivalent of CI Image library(ios) in android?

Tags: android, ios, filter, core-image

I have seen the excellent default library called Core Image in iOS. How to apply same filters in android used in iOS Core image filters?Is there any equivalent library in android? or how to use core image library in android?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some image processing libraries that might help you:

[image]

Here are the links:

- [GPUImage for
  Android](https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage)
- [Android Image Filtering](https://code.google.com/p/android-image-filtering/)
- [Android Fast Image Processing](https://github.com/chrisbatt/AndroidFastImageProcessing)
- [Fresco Processors](https://github.com/wasabeef/fresco-processors)
- [Glide Transformations](https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations)
- [ImageProcessingLib](https://github.com/jcmore2/ImageProcessingLib)
- [JJIL](https://code.google.com/p/jjil/)
- [Picasso Transformations - TannerPerrien](https://github.com/TannerPerrien/picasso-transformations)
- [Picasso Transformations - wasabeef](https://github.com/wasabeef/picasso-transformations)

The source and compilation of all these libraries for Android can be found [here](https://android-arsenal.com/free).

Answer (score 0):

openCV is the best one.supported for all the platforms.